# Building a Wordpress App

Tags: php, admin

I construction of a administrative back office inside the wordpress theme for running our travel company, monitoring users, bookings and payments, it has come to my attention that it might be better served and more secure if such an area were in face a desktop application or offline webpage that connected to the internet inly to get the date.

So how would one connect to wordpress from html/php pages sitting on the desktops of relevant computers? And is that a sensible idea or not?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious how/where you got the impression that desktop apps are more secure than the WP admin.

For better security, you can enable SSL for the normal WP admin web interface, by adding this line to wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: If that is the case then I suppose their would be no problem with a booking system that is online?

Comment: Well, what do 7 milion google results for "online booking system" tell you? :)

Comment: I quite understand that but their are advantages to cache data. I wondered if it might be better to use filemaker and the server since we have worked with FMpro before. Any thoughts on that?\

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Filemaker or FMPro. Your initial question was about security, while this last comment is about wether to build an application using WP or something else. Maybe try asking a new question, with more specifics.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage your WordPress installation over the XML-RPC service. Its a webservice like SOAP which you can query with pre-defined methods. Check out the [official codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) for more information or read [my own article](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webeo.ch%2Fjournal%2Fwordpress-fernsteuern-mittels-xml-rpc) (german) about extending the xml-server class.